# What is the best way to write deviceless tests?

Tags: api, testing, mobile, automation, software-quality

We want to start covering our application (android/ios) with e2e tests,
However in my experience it's hard and nearly impossible to automate mobile applications in a scalable and reliable way so we'are thinking to go with deviceless testing on the api-levelm they are faster and more reliable.

Any recommendations?

I was able to find loadmill,
https://loadmill.com/

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual devices: Use tools such as emulators and simulators to simulate the behavior of physical devices. These tools can help you test your application on multiple devices without having to own them.
Use automation.
Use real world scenarios.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).